# Cherry-pick multiple commits in smartGit but only first few commits are shown in the result of the target branch

Tags: git, cherry-pick, smartgit

I am using smartGit as the tool, say, I checked out branch A and need to bring some commits in branch B to branch A and those commits are not adjacent and could be spread apart in time of commits in branch B. I noticed that after selecting multiple commits in branch B and clicking "cherry pick & commit" button, I got a conflict, then, I resolved it using the "conflict resolver" button, then, staging the resolved file, then, after committing, at this point I can see only few commits that I selected in branch B were brought into branch A, not all commits I selected in branch B?

I am not sure if this has anything to do with the conflict or just too many commits have been selected: I also tried to select only 2 commits (these 2 commits are adjacent in branch B) from branch B and no conflict happened, and I am able to see both commits in branch A.

Any hints are highly appreciated!

Comment: What is your git version? In the early versions, if you use `git commit` to finish a midway conflict, the left commits are not to be cherry picked automatically. `git cherry-pick --continue` finishes the conflict and continues to deal with the left commits. Besides, if the changes of a commit have been already applied to the target branch, maybe by another commit or maybe they have existed from the initial commit, the cherry pick would pause and it expects `git cherry-pick --skip` or `git commit --allow-empty` before it goes on.

Comment: as @ElpieKay said : from the command line you would run `git cherry-pick --continue` to proceed with your cherry pick list (and by the way, you can do that: open a terminal and run `git cherry-pick --continue`). Search SmartGit's interface to see if some action looks like it would proceed with an ongoing cherry-pick.

Comment: Sorry guys, I am using smartGit as the client tool, not using command line at all. Its version is 21.1.2. I am wondering in this case, the tool should show a "Continue" button to let me continue to pick those not merged into the target branch or I just need to do another round of Cherry-pick by picking those commits not merged into target branch?